# Focus on Next Entry after max length of 1

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have created dynamic 20 entries and want to focus on next entry after user enter a digit and max length of entry is 1. The focus should be automatically move on next entry.I am sharing my code.Thanks in advance for help.

//model

```
 public  class CrossingUIModel
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FieldValue { get; set; }      
   }
```

//on change property

```
private ObservableCollection<CrossingUIModel> bindCrossingUIModel;

    public ObservableCollection<CrossingUIModel> BindCrossingUIModel
  {
    get { return bindCrossingUIModel; }
    set
    {
            bindCrossingUIModel = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BindCrossingUIModel));
    }
  }
```

//creating ui

```
  public void CreateUI()
    {
        UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading();

        BindCrossingUIModel = new ObservableCollection<CrossingUIModel>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++)
        {
            CrossingUIModel model = new CrossingUIModel();
            model.Id = i;
            BindCrossingUIModel.Add(model);
        }

        UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();

    }
```

//xml file

```
           <CollectionView x:Name="CrossingView" ItemsSource="{Binding BindCrossingUIModel, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Multiple">
                        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"  Span="10" />
                    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Entry x:Name="Fields" Text="{Binding FieldValue, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                       ReturnType="Next" MaxLength="1" Keyboard="Numeric" 
                                       TextChanged="Fields_TextChanged" ></Entry>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you had used Data-Binding , it would be better to handle all the logic in ViewModel .

#### in code behind

Define a custom Entry

```
public class MyEntry:Entry
{

     public static readonly BindableProperty IsFocusProperty =BindableProperty.Create("IsFocus", typeof(bool), typeof(MyEntry), false,propertyChanged: OnChanged);


    static void OnChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var entry = bindable as MyEntry;

        var focus = (bool)newValue;

        if(focus)
        {
            entry.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            entry.Unfocus();
        }

    }

    public bool IsFocus
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsFocusProperty); }
        set { 
            SetValue(IsFocusProperty, value);
            }
    }

    public MyEntry()
    {
        this.Focused += MyEntry_Focused;
        this.Unfocused += MyEntry_Unfocused;
    }

    private void MyEntry_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsFocus = false;
    }

    private void MyEntry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsFocus = true;
    }
}
```

#### in Model

```
public  class CrossingUIModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int Id { get; set; }
   
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    string fieldValue;

    public string FieldValue
    {

        get
        {
            return fieldValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (fieldValue != value)
            {
                fieldValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FieldValue");
            }
        }
    }


    bool isFocus = false;

    public bool IsFocus
    {
        get
        {
            return isFocus;
        }

        set
        {
            if (isFocus != value)
            {
                isFocus = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsFocus");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

#### in ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<CrossingUIModel> BindCrossingUIModel { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        BindCrossingUIModel = new ObservableCollection<CrossingUIModel>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++)
        {
            CrossingUIModel model = new CrossingUIModel();
            model.Id = i;
            BindCrossingUIModel.Add(model);
        }

        foreach (CrossingUIModel model in BindCrossingUIModel)
        {
            model.PropertyChanged += Model_PropertyChanged;
        }


    }

    private void Model_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.PropertyName== "FieldValue")
        {
            var model = sender as CrossingUIModel;

            if(model.FieldValue.Length==1)
            {
                model.FieldValue = model.FieldValue.Substring(0, 1);

                model.IsFocus = false;

                int id = model.Id;

                BindCrossingUIModel[id].IsFocus = true;

            }

        }
    }
}
```

#### in xaml

Now we don't need to set **MaxLength** and **TextChanged** any more .

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <CollectionView x:Name="CrossingView" ItemsSource="{Binding BindCrossingUIModel, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout  Orientation="Vertical"  Span="10" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <local:MyEntry WidthRequest="80" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" HeightRequest="30" x:Name="Fields" Text="{Binding FieldValue, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                       IsFocus="{Binding IsFocus, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                       ReturnType="Next"  Keyboard="Numeric" 
                                        ></local:MyEntry>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
```

By the way , you could use **Grid** instead of **StackLayout** as the Parent Layout of the Entry.

[image]

Comment: code is running fine but i have a question that does i have to create anything in xamarin.android

Comment: What do you want to do now?

Comment: i want to know that do i have to create any refrence class in my native android ?

Comment: You don’t need to do it

Comment: Sir thanks again for great help and working fine with these code but having some problem on this code that keyboard is hiding after each input that should be stable.if you can help me ,I'ill be very thank full to u.

Comment: What means of  `should be stable` ? The keyboard will hide and display again when we change the input element . It is by design .

Comment: sir stable means that keyboard should not hide it should always visible after every input.

Comment: You could create a new question with more details so that I can help you better